# How to trace system calls in android with not rooted device?

Tags: android

My plan is to make a mobile application that traces system calls of other mobile application like strace. I read some papers but they uses custom kernel or rooted device(emulator). Also I used frida but it requires root privilege.

I want to trace system calls using my mobile application with not rooted device. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Hopefully not, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a way, but there is no official way.

Each app in Android is run in a `Sandbox` which it can't escape. The System has its own `Sandbox` (sometimes multiple), which you can't access.

This is a security measure.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can track are broadcasts.
Without root privilegs it is imho impossible to access system calls.

it would be a huge security issue for android systems if applications could do that.